# importing project from eclipse to android

Tags: android

i am importing project of eclipse in to android studio and when i do after indexing it give me `android plug in id not found`.and below it give me the option of open file when i click thee file below opens
apply plugin: `com.android.application`

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile project(':gesture-imageview')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}

}
```

Comment: Post your logcat here.

Answer (score 0):

try to add inside, `android {...}` , below `buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"`
:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.your.app.id'
    minSdkVersion 15 //your minsdk
    targetSdkVersion 22 /your targetsdk
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Beside that, I think that Hamees Arshad is using an old gradle version too